# What is the preferred way to find all other clients on local network?

Tags: iphone, networking

Writing an iPhone app in which I want to save the user the grief of typing in IP addresses by finding other clients on the local network.

- Is this possible?
- If so, what is the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use Bonjour. See [NSNetService](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This class is used to advertise information about the service you're running using multicast DNS. Use `NSNetServiceBrowser` to find published services of the type you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The clients need some way to register with the server. Or you can use portknocking. Long time back there was a protocol from Novell SLP. There is a OpenSLP now. Found a interesting link, I hope this helps

http://www.opendoor.com/shareway/slp.html